# How to create a view in oracle with dynamic columns

Tags: oracle, file, dynamic, view, pivot

We have a main table that contains 5 columns, we need to load file that the columns in this file vary each time which means sometimes the file contains 8 columns five of them the same field exists in the main table and sometimes 10 fields five of them the same of main table and etc.., 
Main table called population and its structure as below

pop_rec_id, name, age, address, transaction_date

data example:
152,john,26,palestine,1/1/2015

the file will be loaded into extra table called population_extra_fields and its structure as below

id,pop_rec_id(foreign key for population table),column_name,column_value

data example:
1,152,segment,high
2,152,region,West bank
3,152,city,Rammallah

we need to have a dynamic view to retrieve the data from both tables and the column names in the view should be the same as the names from population table and the column names from population_extra_fields

the view result should look like below based on the above data

pop_rec_id | name| age|address  |transaction_date| segment|region    | city

152        | john| 26 |palestine|1/1/2015        | high   | west bank| rammallah

Comment: can you please give me more details @Raj_Te

Comment: You cannot have dynamic column names in a view (or a materialized view).  The underlying approach seems rather problematic-- storing additional column names and values in an EAV model is going to be problematic.  Assuming that you don't need to join or filter this object, you could write a stored procedure which used dynamic SQL to generate the query, open a cursor, and return the cursor to the caller which could fetch the data but that removes a lot of the functionality of a view.  In theory, a pipelined table function can be built that returns a dynamic set of columns but that is complex!

Comment: what about using pivot table, can it help ?@JustinCave

Comment: You can use the PIVOT operator but that requires that you know the column names at compile time so it wouldn't be dynamic.  As I mentioned, you could write a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL to generate the query.  That dynamic SQL could dynamically build the PIVOT statement you want.  But that wouldn't be a view and couldn't be used in joins, couldn't be efficiently filtered, etc.  If you're just returning a result to a front end that reads all the data, a stored function/ stored procedure may be sufficient.

Comment: @JustinCave many thanks for reply, i'm very appreciate your effort, can you give any suggestion about these case?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the data.  With your data model, a view is likely out.  A function doing dynamic SQL and returning a `sys_refcursor` is technically possible but may not work for you if you're trying to join to this.  A pipelined table function with dynamic columns is possible but it is extraordinarily complicated.  The alternative would be to change the data model so that you're adding real columns to the table or to re-create a view with a static set of columns every time a new custom column is added.